# Cannot find App.xaml.cs anywhere

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend

so I'm making my first windows phone app(in Expression Blend 4 as I am more of a designer than a coder), and I notice that by default, there are no transitions between pages. I google around, and all the solutions to creating these transitions seem to require setting `RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();` in the App.xaml.cs file. Problem is, I can't find that file. Is it somewhere hidden or do I have to make it myself? Is there an easier way to do the transitions that I have missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Expand out the App.xaml in the solution explorer.

Comment: Ah, thanks. But I only get App.xaml.vb, although on closer inspection this seems to have the `RootFrame` property I need to edit. Still not sure why its .vb and not .cs though.

Comment: Because you used the Visual Basic Project Template instead of the C# Project Template when you created your project.