# Adding items to Windows 8 Settings Charms Bar

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, hyperlink, privacy, charms-bar

I would like to add a button to the Settings charms bar called 'Privacy Policy' that links to the url:

```
    http://yourdomain.com/privacypolicy
```

I am creating a Windows 8 application using visual studio and VB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vb code in your App.xaml.vb file :

```
    Imports Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings
```

Place in the onlaunched sub

```
    AddHandler SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView.CommandsRequested, Sub(sender, e)         e.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(New SettingsCommand("privacy", "Online Privacy Policy", Sub() privacyGo()))
```

Create a sub

```
    Private Sub privacyGo()

    Dim privacy As New Uri("http://myprivacy.com")

    Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(privacy)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In app.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnWindowCreated(WindowCreatedEventArgs args)
{
    SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += (s, e) =>
    {
        SettingsCommand defaultsCommand = new SettingsCommand("privacy", "Privacy Policy",
            (handler) =>
            {
                //open the URL
                Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://yourdomain.com/privacypolicy"));
            });
        e.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(defaultsCommand);
    };

    base.OnWindowCreated(args);
}
```

Comment: I used the Visual Basic Project Template instead of the C# Project Template when I created the project project so I do not have App.xaml.cs - I only have App.xaml.vb.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976597/cannot-find-app-xaml-cs-anywhere

Comment: I'm sorry, my fault.
But rewriting that code for VB should not be that hard! Give it a try.

Comment: This is what I am getting now: 'Error 1 'Public Event SettingsPane()' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event'